# Setting up an alias name for jar in artifactory

Tags: java, gradle, build, artifactory

I have a gradle project where the jar is built and pushed to artifactory. I always want every build/new artifact to be referred as the latest which can be used externally. How do I achieve it through gradle? Can I set up something like 'latest' alias for the artifact, so at any point in time my latest tag would be pointing the latest jar which can be added as dependency?

Eg : abc-1.0-latest.jar should always fetch me the latest build irrespective of how many builds I run internally.

Answer (score 1):

Hm - that might be a quite odd thing to do?

So, you'd like to publish an artifact several times with the same versioning, but with different signature? That is; the artifact `abc-1.0` can evolve, but the versioning stays the same? Don't know if that is a good practise.

Anyway, why not look in to the versioning of maven/gradle works? Might be that you can add something like this to always fetch the newest artifact of the `abc`-library:

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
  <groupId>com.whatever</groupId>
  <version>[1.0,)</version>
<dependency>
```

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.whatever:abc:1.+'
}
```

In this case, the version 1.1, if available, it will be fetched from artifactory.

Keep in mind, though, that your code will not be easy to rebuild, as the artifact will be fetched using a dynamically dependency approach.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case does sound very strange and not according to best practices.

It looks like what you really need is to use [maven snapshot versions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_a_SNAPSHOT_version).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid specifying the version at all then Gradle will pick the latest one

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:+'
}
```

or if you want the latest of 7 release

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:7.+'
}
```

EDIT: sorry I misunderstood the question.
if you want your project always use the latest code is it not better to create a multi-project in this situation and rely on the project 'build' outcome?